# How do I export favorites from Firefox and Import them in IE11?

Tags: firefox, script, internet-explorer, bookmarks

I am looking at guidance write a script to export favorites from Firefox and import them in IE. any thoughts?

Comment: What does you research tell you?

Comment: Thanks the UI is useful but can't do that on a large estate. Need some form of script. My research indicates it is not possible as FF stores the info in a sort of database based on JSON while IE stores them in a folder as shortcuts. MSDN indicates it has AddFavorites and ImportExportFavorites (deprecated) but not much useful.

Comment: it is possible .. there is an about:config setting to store the html file when the browser quits: browser.bookmarks.autoExportHTML .. so you could script

Answer (score 0):

#### How do I export favorites from Firefox and import them in IE?

> **Exporting bookmarks from Firefox**
>
> 1. Click the Bookmarks button Bookmarks [image] and select Show All Bookmarks to open the Library window.
> 2. From the toolbar on the Library window, click Import and Backup and choose Export Bookmarks to HTML....
>
>    [image: Exporting HTML Bookmarks - Win fx7]
> 3. In the Export Bookmarks File window that opens, choose a location to save the file, which is named bookmarks.html by default.
>      The desktop is usually a good spot, but any place that is easy to
>      remember will work.
> 4. Click the Save button. The Export Bookmarks File window will close.
> 5. Close the Library window.
>
> Your bookmarks are successfully exported from Firefox. To import them
>   into Internet Explorer, proceed to the next section.
>
> **Importing bookmarks into Internet Explorer**
>
> Note: The following steps are for Internet Explorer 9 and above. Steps
>   for previous versions may be slightly different.
>
> 1. Start Internet Explorer.
> 2. Press the Alt key on your keyboard. The menu bar (with File, Edit, View, etc.) will appear.
> 3. Click on the File menu and select Import and Export.... The Import/Export Settings window will appear.
>
>    [image: Importing IE Favorites 1]
> 4. In the Import/Export Settings window, click to select Import from a file and then click the Next button.
> 5. Select Favorites and then click the Next button.
> 6. Click the Browse button. The Select Bookmark File window will open.
>
>    [image: 76bcb3a108d46d756d2677d644020564-1286452173-825-7.png]
> 7. Locate the bookmarks.html file you previously created and then click the Open button.
> 8. The full location of the bookmarks.html file will be shown in the text box. Click on the Next button.
>
>    [image: 76bcb3a108d46d756d2677d644020564-1286452173-825-8.png]
> 9. Click on the Favorites folder and click on the Import button.
>
>    [image: 76bcb3a108d46d756d2677d644020564-1286452173-825-9.png]
> 10. It may take a minute or two for your bookmarks to be imported,
>       depending on how many you have. This final page lets you know we have
>       completed importing our bookmarks. Click on the Finish button, to
>       complete the import.
>
>     [image]

Source [Export bookmarks to Internet Explorer](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/export-bookmarks-internet-explorer)

Comment: -1 The OP is looking for a script.